# Functions passed to meteor template in context are stripped away

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I am passing a context object into my meteor/handlebars template called `menu` from javascript with

```
var context = {
    keyForString: 'string!',
    keyForFunction: function(){console.log('function!');}
};

return Template.menu(context); //to be rendered later
```

In my Template.menu.functions, the `this` variable only has `keyForString`.  `keyForFunction` (and the function) have apparently been stripped away.

Is this expected?  If so, how can I pass a callback to my template code?  I want to provide a function that the template should call when an item on the menu is clicked.

My hope is that instances of the template can share layout code but not have to share events.  For example, I'd have something like

```
Template.menu.events = {
    'click button': function() { 
        this.keyForFunction(); 
    }
}
```

so that clicking the button in instance A can do one thing and clicking the button in B can do another, depending on the function I pass in in `keyForFunction`.

Comment: The normal way to accomplish that is with template [events](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events). Is there some reason why that won't work for you?

Comment: I want to render the same template in multiple places but with different actions.  My hope is that instances A and B can share layout code but not have to share events.  For example, I'd have something like `Template.menu.events = {'click button': function() { this.keyForFunction(); }}` so that clicking the button in A does one thing and clicking the button in B does another.  How would you accomplish this with plain template events?

Comment: (I just updated the question with a more thorough explanation of my motives)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this works perfectly as written above. Storing the objects in `Session`, which I was doing but thought was irrelevant, is what strips the functions out.